# Obtaining Cuban tourist card at Cancun airport for Filipino citizens

Tags: visas, filipino-citizens, cuba, cancun

According to Interjet, it's possible to buy a tourist card to Cuba at their airport counter at Cancun airport. From what I've read, tourist cards for Filipino citizens are only given out when having a valid U.S visa.

Do you know of any Filipinos with a valid U.S visa being able to buy a tourist card to Cuba at Cancun airport? From Interjet or in any other capacity.

Comment: What type of US visa? If you are a US resident you are caught by the travel restrictions https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/132811/i-am-a-us-citizen-that-also-has-israeli-citizenship-can-i-leave-the-us-on-my-am

Comment: @Traveller Not a US resident. I don't know the name of the visa but it's one of those valid for years that you just renew

Comment: Related https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/120223/ofac-declaration-for-travelling-to-cuba-from-us